# convert python sqlite db to hdf5

Tags: python, sqlite, hdf5

A Pandas DataFrame can be converted to a hdf5 file like this;

`df.to_hdf('test_store.hdf','test',mode='w')`

I have an sqlite db file which has to be converted to a hdf5 file and then I would read the hdf5 file through pandas using `pd.read_hdf`.

But first how do I convert a python sqlite db to a hdf5 file ?

EDIT:

I am aware of using the `.read_sql` method in pandas. But I would like to convert the db to hdf5 first.

Answer (score 6):

This is surprisingly simple: Use pandas!

pandas supports [reading data directly from a SQL database](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-sql) into a DataFrame. Once you've got the DataFrame, you can do with it as you wish.

Short example, taken [from the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-sql):

```
import sqlite3
from pandas.io import sql
# Create your connection.
cnx = sqlite3.connect('mydbfile.sqlite')

# read the result of the SQL query into a DataFrame
data = sql.read_sql("SELECT * FROM data;", cnx)

# now you can write it into a HDF5 file
data.to_hdf('test_store.hdf','test',mode='w')
```

Comment: I am aware of the `.read_sql' method. But I'm handling issues of size here and hence would like to convert the db to hdf5 first.

Comment: @richie I've added the final step to convert to HDF5. I thought that was obvious, given your question.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this ---

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_limit_clause.htm

The idea would be to iterate a `select * from table` query and limit the results with an increasing offset. Write the results to the hdf5 data store as shown above. First count the number of entries with a `select count(*) from table` and then split the iteration with into a managble chunks of this. e.g if there are 4million records read 200,000 at a time and increase the offet from 0, 200000, 400000 etc...

I need to do this to a very large sqlite file. will report if it works.